# SWIG: passing bytes between Python and C

Tags: python, c, swig, python-c-api

I have searched online for a while, but what is the correct way to pass bytes to and fro between Python and C? I have leveraged the example from SWIG documentation:

**C Code:**

```
char* foo(char *buff, int size)
{
    return buff;
}
```

**Wrapper code:**

```
%include <pybuffer.i>

%pybuffer_binary(char *buff, int size);
char* foo(char *buff, int size);
```

**Error:**

```
example_wrap.c: In function ‘_wrap_foo’:
example_wrap.c:3385:19: error: ‘size’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     arg2 = (int) (size / sizeof(char));               
example_wrap.c:3385:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
example_wrap.c:3387:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   result = (char *)foo(arg1,arg2);
```

EDIT: 
the Include pybuffer.i: https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/python/pybuffer.i

Comment: Could you also post *pbuffer.i*?

Comment: @CristiFati: Sure, here: https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/python/pybuffer.i